# What C++ objects (of standard type or STYL) can't be copy assigned to another of the same type?

Tags: c++

This is in regards to standard C++ types or containers in STL, so not custom user defined types.

The ones that I can think of are references and `unique_ptr` objects. The latter can be move assigned, but not copy assigned. What other types are there that doesn't allow its objects to be assigned to another of the same type?

Comment: Are you asking about standard types that don't allow copy assignment?  User defined types can be made non-copyable by making the copy constructor and copy assignment operators unavailable, and this is how `unique_ptr` does it.

Comment: Any type you define with a deleted copy assignment operator?

Comment: Are you interested in every possible type? References aren't objects using C++-specific terminology.

Comment: @StephenNewell Yes. Sorry for the ambiguity. I just edited the post with that information.

Comment: @chris I just edited the post. I'm just interested in C++ standard types or those in STL

Comment: @Iamanon: What is the point of this question? You can look at the definition of any standard library class and find out if it is copyable or not. This is not hidden information. So why do you need a list of such types?

Answer (score 3):

1. For commonly known data types, the followings are not copy-assign-able: `std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable`, `int[2]`, `std::thread`. (You can see that many data structures associated with threads are not copy-assign-able)
2. Generally speaking, starting from c++11, if someone marks the copy assign operator of a class to `delete`, then an object of this class is not copy-assign-able. Similarly, if the copy assign operator is marked as `private`, the objects are not copy-assign-able unless the copy assignment happens inside the class.
3. If some members in the class are marked as `const`, which means the members are not changable, then the copy assign operator of the class is by default marked as `delete` by the compiler. E.g., each entry in a `std::map<int, int>`: `std::pair<const int, int>`.

One last note is that if you want to know whether a given class is copy-assign-able, you can use `std::is_copy_assignable<T>` to check.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

struct Foo {
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
};

struct FooWithConstMember {
    const int a = 0;
};

struct FooWithPrivateCopyAssigner {
private:
  auto& operator=(const FooWithPrivateCopyAssigner&) { return *this; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << "int[2] is copy-assignable? "
              << std::is_copy_assignable<int[2]>::value << '\n'
              << "mutex is copy-assignable? "
              << std::is_copy_assignable<std::mutex>::value << '\n'
              << "condition variable is copy-assignable? "
              << std::is_copy_assignable<std::condition_variable>::value << '\n'
              << "Foo is copy-assignable? "
              << std::is_copy_assignable<Foo>::value << '\n'
              << "std::pair<const int, int> is copy-assignable? "
              << std::is_copy_assignable<std::pair<const int, int>>::value << '\n'
              << "FooWithConstMember is copy-assignable? "
              << std::is_copy_assignable<FooWithConstMember>::value << '\n'
              << "FooWithPrivateCopyAssigner is copy-assignable? "
              << std::is_copy_assignable<FooWithPrivateCopyAssigner>::value << '\n'
    ;
}
```

The output is

```
int[2] is copy-assignable? false
mutex is copy-assignable? false
condition variable is copy-assignable? false
Foo is copy-assignable? false
std::pair<const int, int> is copy-assignable? false
FooWithConstMember is copy-assignable? false
FooWithPrivateCopyAssigner is copy-assignable? false
```